# rake db:migrate is not creating data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to add a Devise admin user using the migration. I tried running the following with --trace, but don't see any issues.  My migrate file is:

```
 class InsertAdminUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    User.new(:email => "abc@abc.com", :name => "abc", :password => "abc", admin => true)
  end

  def down
    User.delete_all(:email => "abc@abc.com")
  end
end
```

When I run db:migrate it runs fine but the user is not created.

Any idea of why it is not creating the user, or how I can further debug?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
User.new(:email => "abc@abc.com", :name => "abc", :password => "abc", admin => true)
```

with

```
User.create!(:email => "abc@abc.com", :name => "abc", :password => "abc", admin => true)
```

[create!](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#valid-and-invalid) will raise an error if record is not created

Comment: Thanks, but same result, no errors, but no record gets created.

Comment: may be you have set some validation rules on user model, try using create! and see which Validation is getting failed.

Comment: I tried using create! but it did not show any errors when I ran db:migrate, does it log them somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason why you want to do this in a migration file?
I think putting this kind of migration into a seed file would be a more sensible solution.

Put 
User.create!(:email => "abc@abc.com", :name => "abc", :password => "abc", admin => true) in
seed.rb and run rake db:seed

you can also create custom seeding files,
for example, create seed_admin.rb and put

```
User.create!(:email => "abc@abc.com", :name => "abc", :password => "abc", admin => true)
```

create delete_admin.rb and put

```
User.delete_all(:email => "abc@abc.com")
```

then you can run

```
rake db:seed:seed_admin and rake db:seed:delete_admin
```

If you are putting your code to github do not forget to put those sensitive files in .gitingore